# Python. График на mathplotlib

Tags: python

Создал график с помощью библиотеки mathplotlib. График получился ужасно неразборчивый. Нужно сделать нормальный график по координатам. Прикрепляю код:

```
import matplotlib
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pmdarima as pm
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split


 class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = ""
        self.x = ""

    #Метод на заполнение x.txt и y.txt
    def Fill(self):
        n = 144
        xlist = []
        xa = open("x.txt", "w")
        with xa as xlist:
            for i in range(n):
                xlist.writelines(str(random.randint(10, 99)) + '\n')
        xa.close()

        ylist = []
        ya = open("y.txt", "w")
        with ya as ylist:
            for i in range(n):
                ylist.writelines(str(random.randint(10, 99)) + '\n')
        ya.close()

    #Метод для вывода графика на экран
    def Screen(self):
        n = 144
        x = np.array([])
        with open("x.txt") as xlist:
            for line in xlist:
                x = np.loadtxt(xlist.readlines(int()))
                self.fx = x

        y = np.array([])
        with open("y.txt") as ylist:
            for line in ylist:
                y = np.loadtxt(ylist.readlines(int()))
                self.fy = y

        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()




gra = Graph()
gra.Fill()
gra.Screen()
```

[image: Сам график]

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Вы правы, забыл указать. Нужно сделать нормальный график по координатам, а не такую мешанину.

Comment: Судя по всему, график у вас и так строится по координатам, только они у вас не упорядочены.

Comment: А вы не знаете оптимальный метод для сортировки координат?

Comment: Сделайте по `x` просто `i`. `xlist.writelines(str(i) + '\n')` А то у вас куча точек и так перезаписывается.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отсортировать значения `x` по возрастанию, и сопоставить им соответствующие значений `y`

```
import matplotlib
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# моделируем ваш случай
n=144
x = []
y = []
for i in range(n):
    x.append(random.randint(10, 99))
for i in range(n):
    y.append(random.randint(10, 99))

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Поскольку у вас все значения выбраны случайным образом и не отсортированы, получается мешанина типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам нужно просто отсортировать значения по оси абсцисс, но не забыть про соответствующие им значения по оси ординат:

```
X, Y = zip(*sorted(list(zip(x,y))))
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

получаем на тех же, но упорядоченных данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Спасибо за ответ